# Controller drivers won't install on Windows 7

Tags: guitar-hero

I want to play Guitar Hero III Legends of Rock on PC, with the guitar controller for Xbox 360 via USB. But when I plug the guitar into my computer, Windows 7 searches for drivers and does not find them on Windows Update. So my guitar won't work in game.
I searched Google for Guitar Hero III X-plorer drivers, so I could download them and install them manually, but I didn't find anything. Instead I saw many forums where people had the same problem as me and were complaining that drivers weren't available in any way. I tried every answer I saw but nothing worked (that included manipulating stuff in the device manager, installing [this](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/xbox-360-controller-for-windows), and even rebooting the computer, reinstall the game and other BS). My computer won't recognize my guitar.
I think Microsoft just deleted these drivers from Windows Update, at least for Windows 7, because a friend with Windows 8 instantly installs the right driver when he plugs the guitar in, and everything works perfectly fine (we tested this with the same guitar and the same game).
I heard about JoyToKey, which is supposed to "convert" controller button presses to keystrokes on a keyboard, but it doesn't work as my controller isn't recognized and doesn't appear in the device list.

Does anyone have ideas ? :(

Comment: When you plug the controller in to your PC, does it appear in the Game Controllers list? (Start -> Set up USB game controllers)

Comment: No, it doesn't.
EDIT: The only place where it does appear is the device manager, under the "Other devices" section (not sure about the exact titles, my Windows is french).

Comment: You may want to test it with another PC (maybe your friend's Windows 8 machine) or with an Xbox to see if the controller itself is working. I believe those controllers are supposed to be plug-and-play with both Xbox and Windows machines.

Comment: Yes, we already tested the very same controller on his Windows 8 computer. And I think it worked on his computer because Windows 8 was able to get drivers from Windows update, and Windows 7 can't seem to do that.

Comment: Alright, that's good to know. Try this: in Device Manager, locate the guitar controller under Human Interface Devices. Right-click -> properties -> Driver tab -> Update Driver -> Search automatically. That may be able to find it, or it will at least tell you it cannot find them.

Comment: I can't find it under human interface devices, so here's a screenshot to summarize the situation : http://puu.sh/bsqHj/e521a9666a.png EDIT: I tried with the Guitar controller in "Other device" and it didn"t work (it couldn't find drivers).

Comment: Okay, so it looks like there was a driver error, as evidenced by that little yellow circle on Guitar Hero X-Plorer. You could try uninstalling the driver for it: right-click -> Uninstall. Then, you can try Updating the driver again automatically and see if it installs correctly. Otherwise, see if you can capture an error message or error code. Je peux parler en français si c'est plus facile aussi.